# Multidimensional Array - Search for value and get the sub-array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

Given an array like

```
$clusters = array(
"clustera" => array(
    '101',
    '102',
    '103',
    '104'
),
"clusterb" => array(
    '201',
    '202',
    '203',
    '204'
),
"clusterc" => array(
    '301',
    '302',
    '303',
    '304'
)
);
```

How can I search for a server (e.g. 202) and get back its cluster? i.e. search for 202 and the response is "clusterb" I tried using array_search but it seems that is only for monodimensional arrays right? (i.e. complains that second argument is the wrong datatype if I give it $clusters)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$search=202;

$cluster=false;

foreach ($clusters as $n=>$c)
  if (in_array($search, $c)) {
    $cluster=$n;
    break;
  }

echo $cluster;
```

Comment: something funky going on. Seemed you missed a brace or something anfd I tried to clean up but can't get it working.    $search=$server;
   $cluster=false;
   foreach ($clusters as $n=>$c) {
     if (in_array($search,$c)) {
       $cluster=$n;
       break;
     }
   }
   print("method 2 got: "$cluster);

Comment: Just checked my code here, works as expected. Your code is wrong in the last line, `print("method 2 got: "$cluster);`should be `print("method 2 got: $cluster");`

Comment: Absolutely right ... but even that was not the issue .... I was testing with 202 when in fact I hid the REAL server name from the example to protect the innocent :) Works great!

Answer (score 3):

```
$arrIt = new RecursiveArrayIterator($cluster);
$server = 202;

foreach ($arrIt as $sub){
    if (in_array($server,$sub)){
        $clusterSubArr = $sub;
        break;
        }
    }

$clusterX = array_search($clusterSubArr, $cluster);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_multi_search($needle,$haystack){
foreach($haystack as $key=>$data){

if(in_array($needle,$data))
return $key;
}
}
$key=array_multi_search(202,$clusters);
echo $key;
$array=$clusters[$key];
```

Try using this function. It returns the key of the $needle(202) in the immediate child arrays of $haystack(cluster). Not tested, so let me know if this works

Comment: This one not quite working either ... comes up empty. The only change I have made is throwing braces around the contents of the function.  function array_multi_search($needle,$haystack) {
 foreach($haystack as $key=>$data) {
  if(in_array($needle,$data)) return $key;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCluster($val) {
   foreach($clusters as $cluster_name => $cluster) {
      if(in_array($val, $cluster)) return $cluster_name;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: hmm I get "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"   which is shame as it looks like it will be exactly what I need :)

Comment: $clusters would need to be defined as your array of clusters as in the question